# Strange behaviour of Array

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Editing the example. I guess the problem is here, but can't understand it :

```
var aa:Number = 3
var a:Array = new Array (3,2) ;
var b:Array = new Array(3); 
fun(a) ;
fun(b);


function fun(c:Object)
{
trace(c[0]);   

}

//output
// 3
// undefined
```

Why i get output undefined in the latter case ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html

```
Array(... values)
```

Lets you create an array that contains the specified elements.

```
Array(numElements:int = 0)
```

Lets you create an array of the specified number of elements.

That's why when you define

```
var b:Array = new Array(3);
```

it creates an array of four elements. And as there is no value  defined in those elements, you get undefined error.

Answer (score 3):

```
new Array(abc)
```

should be

`new Array([abc])`

Without [] you only set the length of array.

Answer (score 2):

So to expand on Mahmut's answer...

Here you create a new array and define it with a length of 3 nodes, but at the moment the nodes are empty.

```
var b:Array = new Array(3);
```

I believe you are expecting the output to trace 3 rather than undefined.

So you could add the item "3" like Mahmut says:

```
var b:Array = new Array([3]);
```

or

```
b.push(3);
```